# Lexical and dynamic scoping in Mathematica: Local variables with Module, With, and Block

Tags: localization, variables, module, scope, wolfram-mathematica

The following code returns 14 as you'd expect:

```
Block[{expr},
  expr = 2 z;
  f[z_] = expr;
  f[7]]
```

But if you change that `Block` to a `Module` then it returns `2*z`.
It seems to not matter what other variables besides `expr` you localize.
I thought I understood Module, Block, and With in Mathematica but I can't explain the difference in behavior between Module and Block in this example.

Related resources:

- [Tutorial on Modularity and the Naming of Things](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview.html) from the Mathematica documentation
- Excerpt from a [book by Paul R. Wellin, Richard J. Gaylord, and Samuel N. Kamin](http://books.google.com/books?id=OuzV1M7b0WIC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=module+block+%22with%22+mathematica&source=bl&ots=HB4e0jDg7L&sig=Q7N3cscoeuc5AHtIzJHHwO0PWv0&hl=en&ei=w7XTS9PALsKqlAfr1ITtDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CCEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=module%20block%20%22with%22%20mathematica&f=false)
- [Explanation from Dave Withoff on the Mathematica newsgroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jan/msg00354.html)

**PS:** Thanks to [Michael Pilat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272923/michael-pilat),  [Davorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128583/davorak), and [Bill White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42629/bill-white) for following the scent-trail on this weirdness.
Davorak clarifies and gets to the heart of the issue here:
[Why would Mathematica break normal scoping rules in Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739643/why-would-mathematica-break-normal-scoping-rules-in-module)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too was a bit surprised by this, but I don't think it's a bug. If you look deep in the examples in the [reference page for `Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html?q=Module&lang=en), under the section labeled **Possible Issues**, there's a little note that says *"Variables are renamed in nested scopes"* and gives the following example:

```
In[1]:= Module[{e = Expand[(1 + x)^5]}, Function[x, e]]

Out[1]= Function[x$, e$1194]

In[2]:= %[10]

Out[2]= 1 + 5 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 5 x^4 + x^5
```

`Function` is another scoping construct like `Module`, so `x` is renamed internally to `x$` in the scope of the `Function`, similar to what you discovered with `Trace` about `z`.

In your `Module` defining `f`, `Set` is another such scoping construct, and therefore `z` is renamed when `f` is defined inside of a `Module`, but not when it's inside a `Block`. Following the advice of that example from the `Module` documentation, you can build the RHS of your function from its parts to avoid the lexical renaming of the nested scope:

```
In[3]:= Clear[f, z]

In[4]:= Module[{expr},
  expr = 2 z;
  Set @@ {f[z_], expr};
  f[7]]

Out[4]= 14
```

HTH!

Comment: Wow, not what I'd call a pretty work-around but impressive work figuring that out!

Comment: This is why I come back to SO every day. Learns me some s**t :-).

Comment: I would rather take the unexpected performance hit of having expr wrapped in a lazy alpha conversion rather then dealing with the inconsistent syntax. What language design considerations are going in to play here?

Comment: This work around is not perfect since f[z_] is no longer held by Set's HoldFirst Attribute. You get a set::write error if you evaluate the example Code twice with out clearing f. Nice catch Michael Pilat.

Comment: Davorak, right, but you could use instead, for example `Set @@ Hold[f[z_], expr]` to avoid that problem. Or, you could use `f = Function@@{z, expr}` Perhaps we need to start using Perl's TMTOWTDI for Mathematica too =)

I can't speak to the exact considerations behind the sub-scope renaming behavior, other than that `f[z_] = ...` is effectively saying you want to treat `z` as a local variable inside the definition of `f`, and the renaming, while sometimes unnecessary, ensures that.

Comment: Good call on the using Hold instead of list. Variable's name is rewritten to keep make a local scope otherwise know as an alpha conversion like I mentioned in my answer. What I want to know is why does the behavior have to be different at all. They made a call to have the syntax be inconsistant rather then face some other problem.  What is that other problem? Which is what I asked over here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739643/why-would-mathematica-break-normal-scoping-rules-in-module

Answer (score 3):

First off I think you have exposed a bug here.

Second I think I can offer some insight in to why this is happening, keeping in mind my knowledge of the internals of mathematica are limited.

A statement like: f[z_] := 2 z in Full form is:

```
SetDelayed[f[Pattern[z, Blank[]]], 2 z]
```

This sets the DownValue[f] to:

```
{HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> 2 z}
```

Then later when an expression, like f[2], is later is evaluated something like following is being preformed:

```
f[2] /. HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> 2 z
```

Which would evaluate to 4.  Now this is all possible because pattern matching is happening with Pattern[z, Blank[]] from the first code block. This works even if you have perviously set z to a number.  In other words.

```
z = 5;
f[z_] := 2*z
```

Still produces the same downvalues for f:

```
{HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> 2 z}
```

This is possible because Pattern has the HoldFirst Attribute.

The HoldFirst Attribute is not enough protection if you evaluate this inside a Module.
Example:

```
SetAttributes[tmp, HoldFirst];
Module[{expr},
 expr = 2 z;
 tmp[expr]
]
```

outputs:

```
tmp[expr$8129]
```

I propose that because HoldFirst Attribute does not provide immunity to Module's variable rewrite rule that any Pattern in a Rule that contains a local variable have their Pattern variables rewritten. sym->Symbol[SymbolName[sym]~~"$"]

```
Module[{expr},
 Hold[z_ -> (z; expr)]
]
(*Hold[z$_ -> (z$; expr$1391)]*)
```

z has be rewritten on both sides of the rule in a simple alpha conversion.

If the rule does not contain a local variable no rewrite happens:

```
Module[{expr},
 Hold[z_ -> (z)]
]
(*Hold[z_ -> z]*)
```

Rather then searching to see if a local variable matches a rule variable the above blanket rule is applied.

So the problem is that the local expr is not evaluated before the alpha conversion takes place. Or perhaps even better would be to have expr wrapped in a lazily evaluated alpha conversion which would be required for a RuleDelayed.

This does not happen in Block because Block does not rewrite any of the local variables.

Any other ideas?
Any one see any holes in my logic?

Comment: Thanks so much, Davorak.  It seems like you and Michael Pilat are getting at the same issue, right?

Comment: It is the same issue. The alpha conversion gives scoping to Function, Rule, Set, SetDelayed, but the rewritten variables are still in the global namespace. I guess I was wrong about it being a bug, but it is rather annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used Trace on both expressions?

Comment: Ah, smart!  So `z_` is getting turned into `z$_` in the Module version.  So I guess that explains it but I still don't understand why that's happening! Maybe I'll update the question though to ask about that weirdness specifically.